# Como definir ícones diferentes no mapa no início e no fim do trajeto?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou desenvolvendo sistema de rastreamento e preciso que ao consultar o trajeto onde o veículo passou. Quero que ponto inicial e final sejam identificados com outro ícone conforme imagem. Segue também código PHP:

```
    while($RS= mysql_fetch_array($RSS)){
    $x = $x + 1;
    $kx .= "new google.maps.LatLng(".str_replace(",", ".", $RS["vl_latitude"]).", ".str_replace(",", ".", $RS["vl_longitude"])."),";

    if($RS["ig"] == "1"){$ig="LIGADA";}else{$ig="DESLIGADA";}
    if($x == 1){$pt = $pt . chr(91)."'INICIO: ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($RS["dt_hora"]))." - ".$RS["ds_posicao"]." | Ig: ".$ig."', ".str_replace(",", ".", $RS["vl_latitude"]).", ".str_replace(",", ".", $RS["vl_longitude"]).", ".$x."],";}else{$pt = $pt . chr(91)."' ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($RS["dt_hora"]))." - ".$RS["ds_posicao"]." | Ig: ".$ig."', ".str_replace(",", ".", $RS["vl_latitude"]).", ".str_replace(",", ".", $RS["vl_longitude"]).", ".$x."],";}
    $adata  = $RS["dt_hora"];
    if($RS["ig"] == "1"){$aig="LIGADA";}else{$aig="DESLIGADA";}
    //$aig  = $RS["ig"];
    $apos   = $RS["ds_posicao"];
    $alat   = $RS["vl_latitude"];
    $alng   = $RS["vl_longitude"];
}
$pt = $pt . chr(91)."'FIM: ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($adata))." - ".$apos." | Ig: ".$aig."', ".str_replace(",", ".", $alat).", ".str_replace(",", ".", $alng).", ".$x."],";
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Função para criação do `Marker`:

```
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../../imagens/car_mini.png',
        new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 10));
    var shape = {
        coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
        type: 'poly'
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var beach = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            shape: shape,
            title: beach[0],
            zIndex: beach[3]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, remova a imagem do código em Javascript e insira o próprio código. Isso facilita pra quem vai te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta criar dentro do laço de repetição um `Marker` diferente criando uma condição para identificar qual primeira e última coordenada registrada. Veja abaixo como deveria ficar seu código:

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../../imagens/car_mini.png',
  new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 10));

var outraImagem = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../../imagens/car.png',
  new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 10));

var shape = {
  coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
  type: 'poly'
};

for (var i = 0; locations.lenght; i++) {

    var beach = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
    });

    // aqui é a primeira posição
    if (i == 0) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: outraImagem,
            shape: shape,
            title: beach[0],
            zIndex: beach[3]
        });
    }

    // aqui é a ultima posição
    if (i == (locations.length - 1)) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: outraImagem,
            shape: shape,
            title: beach[0],
            zIndex: beach[3]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi, e como faço para declarar a segunda imagem?
//imagem1  
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../../imagens/car_mini.png',
      new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 10));

//imagem2 
 var imagem = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../../imagens/car.png',
      new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 10));

seria algo assim?

Comment: @LucasSpielmann faz logo abaixo da primeira porém com um nome diferente. Como no exemplo que dei: outraImagem

Comment: consegue me chamar no whats fazendo favor? nossa vai me ajudar muito mesmo.
49 999290123

Comment: @LucasSpielmann é isso ai mesmo que você fez.

Comment: @LucasSpielmann se tiver mais alguma dúvida, pode perguntar por aqui mesmo! =D

Comment: estranho que não está exibindo os icones desta forma

Comment: @LucasSpielmann está mostrando algum erro?!

Comment: Não, simplesmente quando insiro duas vezes:
  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../../imagens/car_mini.png',
      new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 10));
  var imagem = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../../imagens/car.png',
      new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 10));


ele nao exibe os icones

Comment: @LucasSpielmann viu que eu comentei na sua pergunta. Edite a pergunta e coloque o código em vez da imagem. Isso facilita pra quem está te ajudando. Tem como você fazer isso?!

Comment: não fica identado o codigo javascript, mas vou postar mesmo assim..

Comment: @LucasSpielmann não estou vendo seu código depois da alteração, então fica difícil eu te falar o que está errado.

Comment: posso enviar para seu email o arquivo? talvez fica mais facil

Comment: @LucasSpielmann não cara. Temos que resolver aqui ou no chat. Mas não sei se você tem reputação para entrar no chat.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64578/discussion-between-white-and-lucas-spielmann).